# Changing game AI for Civilization 4

Tags: civilization-4

I read that the auto-worker functionality in Civilization 4 doesn't really work very well - he keeps building farms as opposed to towns and other objects. Since I'm still pretty new to this (and don't play many strategy games except for those similar to Age of Empires, which is pretty simple and straightforward), I went about thinking of the best way to learn this game.

One thing I thought of to do is use an automated worker to do a lot of things while I try to understand what other elements I can control. **Does anyone know whether or not there is an AI that I can use for the auto-worker to improve his behavior?** I know that we download and install custom scripts at least in Age of Empires.

Comment: No problem maaaaaaan. :) Happy holidays!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, no mod changes with the auto worker pattern.  This is mostly because you need to specialize cities, which means that one size does not fit all.  You also have to co-ordinate with the terrain you settle on.  Workers, and city planning are some of the hardest parts of the game.

Take a look at [these guides at civfanatics](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ4/strategy).

Your basic plan for early game is to have 2 or 3 production cities, with lots of food and hammers, as well as 3-5 commerce cities, with cottages.  You don't want cottages in your production cities radius, but you can have a mine in your commerce city, so that you can build things like libraries, banks, or other money or science boosting building.